# TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response

Tags: python, python-requests, character-encoding

Let me quickly summarise what I am getting here... I am using the below URL in my python code to fetch the street, city, country details, but unfortunately, the data being displayed is in unicode, which I am not able to use for further processing.

I tried with/without `&accept-language:%20en-US,en;q=0.3` in the URL:

http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key=mykey&location=40.1388294887,116.6368220285&accept-language:%20en-US,en;q=0.3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "01.py", line 19, in <module>
    obj = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response

[{'place_id': 647521, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'node', 'osm_id': 244081855, 'boundingbox': ['39.9693744', '40.2893744', '116.4887311', '116.8087311'], 'lat': '40.1293744', 'lon': '116.6487311', 'display_name': '**顺义区, 顺义区 / Shunyi, 北京市, 101399, China 中国',** 'class': 'place', 'type': 'city', 'importance': 0.5732222777392743, 'icon': 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_place_city.p.20.png', 'extratags': {'gns:DSG': 'ADM3', 'gns:UFI': '-1926734', 'gns:UNI': '9336415', 'gns:ADM1': '22', 'wikidata': 'Q393482'}}, {'place_id': 235932091, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'relation', 'osm_id': 2988901, 'boundingbox': ['40.0072123', '40.3096879', '116.4588662', '116.9803068'], 'lat': '40.1583306', 'lon': '116.72011452233471', 'display_name': **'顺义区 / Shunyi, 北京市, China 中国**', 'class': 'boundary', 'type': 'administrative', 'importance': 0.5632222777392742, 'icon': '', 'extratags': {'wikidata': 'Q393482', 'wikipedia': 'zh:顺义区'}}]


**http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key=mykey&location=40.1388294887,116.6368220285** 
this gives me a different value.

{"info":{"statuscode":0,"copyright":{"text":"\u00A9 2020 MapQuest, Inc.","imageUrl":"http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif","imageAltText":"\u00A9 2020 MapQuest, Inc."},"messages":[]},"options":{"maxResults":1,"thumbMaps":true,"ignoreLatLngInput":false},"results":[{"providedLocation":{"latLng":{"lat":40.1388294887,"lng":116.6368220285}},"locations":[{"**street":"\u5367\u9F99\u516C\u56ED"**,"adminArea6":"","adminArea6Type":"Neighborhood",**"adminArea5":"\u987A\u4E49\u533A"**,"adminArea5Type":"City","adminArea4":"","adminArea4Type":"County","adminArea3":"Beijing","adminArea3Type":"State","adminArea1":"CN","adminArea1Type":"Country","postalCode":"101399","geocodeQualityCode":"P1AAA","geocodeQuality":"POINT","dragPoint":false,"sideOfStreet":"N","linkId":"0","unknownInput":"","type":"s","latLng":{"lat":40.139906,"lng":116.634866},"displayLatLng":{"lat":40.139906,"lng":116.634866},"mapUrl":"http:}]}]}
```

Below is the snippet of the code which I am using in python script.

```
url = "http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key={}&location={},{}&accept-language=en".format(MY_KEY,var_lat,var_lng)
        
print(url)
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()

# parse json object
obj = json.loads(data)        
#print(data)

            Output is something like this, I wanted the same in english 
            
            Street       :卧龙公园
            City         :顺义区
            State Region :Beijing
            country_short:CN
            Zip          :101399
```

Thanks,
Please help . I need the output in readable format.

Comment: The error in the title is different from the error traceback in the question.

Comment: why not just use `requests.get`